# Open in Zariski but not product topology

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X \subset k^m , Y \subset k^n$ be algebraic sets ($k$ an algebraically closed field). Then $X\times Y \subset k^{m+n}$ is an algebraic set whose Zariski topology is finer than the product topology of the Zariski topologies of the factors. Could someone give me an example that demonstrates that it can be *strictly* finer?

Comment: I'm having trouble being totally rigorous here, but consider affine 2-space as product of affine 1-space with itself.  The basic idea is that not all polynomials in x and y are products of a polynomial in x with a polynomial in y.  To be a little more specific, consider the circle $x^2-y^2-1$ in 2-space.  This should not be closed in the product space.  There is a characterization of closed sets in the product space as intersections of finite unions of products of closed sets, if that helps.  Note here that affine 1-space has the cofinite topology.

Comment: @seth thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I will take $n=m=1$, you will adapt in higher dimensions.) Let $P = X-Y$ and $Z = V(P)$, so that $Z$ is closed. Now $Z = \{(x,x)\;|\; x\in \mathbf{A}_k^1\}$. Now (easy) $Z$ is closed in the product topology if and only if $\mathbf{A}_k^1$ is Hausdorff, and this is not the case as $k$ is infinite, being algebraically closed, and as (independently of $k$ finiteness) the closed sets of the affine line are the whole affine line and finite sets.

Comment: Remark : the following is purely general : a topological space $X$ is Hausdorff if and only if $\Delta_X = \{(x,x)\;|\;x\in X\}$ is closed in $X\times X$, the latter being endowed with the product topology.